# calling revalidate after pressing Jbutton in java

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

I have a frame holding `JPanel` that holds `JButton` buttons having numbers from 1 to 9, when the button is pressed it should change its icon to a predefined icon.

When I initialize the buttons I add an `ActionListener` to each button like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

All the button are inside `JPanel` that has a colored background like the frame it resides in.  My question is, should I call `revalidate` and `repaint` inside `actionPerformed` when the button is pressed?

I am asking this because sometimes when pressing the buttons the background of the frame holding the panel that has the buttons gets distorted.

Please look at the attached pictures to understand what I mean.

When pressing on button holding number 1 or number 4 the background gets deformed.

**This doesn't happen always, and I don't know what is the trigger for this.**

Thanks.

Each button extends a class that extends `JButton` that has the following method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    ButtonModel m = getModel();
    if (m.isPressed() || m.isSelected()) {
        if (on != null)
            on.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    } else if (!isEnabled()) {
        if (disabled != null)
            disabled.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    } else {
        if (off != null)
            off.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    }

    if (m.isPressed() || m.isSelected())
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: `should I call revalidate and repaint inside actionPerformed when the button is pressed?!` - there is no need to do this. Swing will do it for you whenever you change a property of the button. So all you need to do is invoke the `setIcon(...)` method. `I am asking this because sometimes when pressing the buttons the background of the frame holding the panel that has the buttons gets distorted.` - this should not happen you must have so other custom painting that is causing the problem.

Comment: @camickr thanks for your reply, unfortunately I don't have any other paintings in my code except these for the buttons, and I am not calling setIcon method I use paintComponent(Graphics g) and inside it i do : icon.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);

Comment: *"I am not calling setIcon method I use paintComponent(Graphics g) and inside it i do : icon.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);"*. Well probably you deleted the `super.paintComponent(g)` call at the start of your `paintComponent()` method... Or something else, but to know what exactly is causing the issue, you should post a valid [mcve], but I agree with @camickr you should be using the `setIcon(...)` method

Comment: Why are you using paintIcon(...)? A button knows how to paint an Icon, just use the setIcon() method as I stated earlier. Or if you are changing the Icon on a different component you can use a JLabel to paint an Icon. I don't see any reason based on your question for custom painting.

Comment: @Frakcool how do you explain that this doesn't happen always if I forgot something?!

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, instead [edit] your question to add it, it's hard to read it. Again, provide a valid [mcve] that demonstrates that issue. Your problem might be related to some logic in your program

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: `super.paintComponent(g);` you didn't even read my comment above, that line should be the **first** line in your `paintComponent(...) {` method. And I also suggest you not to skip the curly braces for each `if` / `while` / etc statements

Comment: @Frakcool I read but can you explain why it should be the first and what does it mean?

Comment: Please take a look at the [Swing custom painting tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html). `super.paintComponent()` calls the super constructor of the container, if you skip it, you're likely to break the painting chain and will be giving you some strange and random errors related to the GUI painting

Comment: @Frakcool as you can see calling super paintcomponent is not always nedded just in cast the if statement is true!, should I remove the if statement and add the calling to super at the first line that means executing the painting on the parent always?

Comment: *"as you can see calling super paintcomponent is not always nedded"* Why not? Again, it **must** be the first line, it doesn't contain the "default" `JButton` LAF, but rather a set of instructions that paint the `JButton` with the configurations you want. If you want the `JButton` to be like a "default" button you need to change the LAF of the button in that last `if-statement`

Answer (score 2):

> each buttons inherits from superclass that holds the icons, when the button is pressed or unpressed and the superclass has the method

Have you read the API. A button supports methods like:

1. setPressedIcon(...);
2. setSelectedIcon(...);
3. setDisabledIcon(...);
4. read the API for other methods with "Icon" in the method name

Again, I don't understand the need for your custom painting.

> this doesn't happen always!,

It is the responsibility of all Swing components to paint its background. Otherwise that can be garbage. We have no ideas why it is random the complex painting logic in built into Swing. If you follow the rules you won't have a problem.

The first statement of the `paintComponent()` method should always be:

```
super.paintComponent(...)
```

to make sure the background is painted.

Comment: will removing the paintComponent method did not work.